# POST call with authentication to same URL, using Python Requests

Tags: python, authentication, post, python-requests, session-cookies

I am making a POST call to a script at the following URL (internal to my company so can't be accessed from outside): 
https://opsdata.mycompany.com/scripts/finance/finance.exe

The initial site is a html page that has text boxes for you to enter data into, and it has a post action to the above url.  However, it redirects to a login page which is also at the above url that has text boxes for a username and password.  I submit data to the login page using the following code:

```
post_url_finance = 'https://opsdata.*****.com/scripts/finance/finance.exe'
s = requests.session()
s.auth = {'USER_NAME': '*****', 'PASSWORD': '*****'}
proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy-***.****.com'}
```

To do the authentication, I am using:

```
pageCert = requests.post(post_url_finance, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

This gives me a response:

```
<Response [200]>
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:768: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

However, I need to send the data which I am querying for using this info:

```
values_finance = {'EMPLOYEE_TOTAL': '-----'}
```

when I make the post call a second time using:

```
page = requests.post(post_url_finance, data=values_finance, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

I am getting the same response back.

```
<Response [200]>
```

How do I make the second call to Post retrieve the data I want?

Answer (score 0):

all `status_code=200` means is that the website "successfully rendered a page" alot of times sites may not make their invalid login pages or error pages return anything else

you need to look at `pageCert.content` .... I dont think you are actually logging in (maybe you are) ... on your second call you need to do

```
page = s.post(url,...)
```

to get api data you *probably want to use json

```
page_data = s.post(url,...).json()
```

Answer (score 0):

First time I see this thing but docs gave me some guidance... Looks like you're just printing out the response but not the data, have an example:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
print(r)
# <response 200>
# Now if I write the text:
print(r.text)
# A lot of html comes out
```

As @Joran Beasley says, you may need to just use `print(r.json)` to see what you need. In the ideal scenario, getting a 200 response code is a good thing, otherwise you would be getting a 401/403 error if the authentication failed.

The exception has more to do with the authenticity of the certs on the mycompany.com end for what you can read in the urlllib3 docs.